# Per-process CPU/MEM utilization?

Tags: linux, memory, central-processing-unit

Is there any Linux tool that allows to display graphically (on a chart) the per-process CPU/MEM utilisation?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have some sort of platform in mind?

Comment: Sorry! Linux. Sometimes I give that for granted.

Comment: I like you already. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [this munin plugin](http://osdir.com/ml/db.rddtool.munin.general/2007-10/msg00048.html):

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is to take output from 'ps' or 'top' and either graph it using GNUPlot or pull it into a spreadsheet (e.g., OpenOffice) and graph it from there.

KDE's "System Monitor" provides a live view.

There are probably other good choices, depending on whether you want to look at this data live or historically, and what you want to do with it once you have it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Nagios and PNP for this type of thing.... works really well.

http://www.nagios.org/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pnp4nagios/

Answer (score 0):

You can try out SAR, which is really a very good tool and provides information per-process wise.